# Customized Google Play Store alerts on bad reviews

Tags: android, google-play, alerts, review

I would like to be able to receive notifications, when I receive a negative rating with a review on my Google Play Store account. Have any of you tried this and do you know how this can be done?

So far, the only interesting thing I have found are Alerts, but those seem to only be interested in the number of times my applications has been installed and uninstalled. Maybe there is a way that I could get alerts customized?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your [Google Play Developer Console](https://play.google.com/apps/publish/), you can currently receive 4 types of app alerts:

1. Crashes
2. Installs
3. **Average rating.** The Average Rating of your app has significantly decreased compared to the previous week. If the Average Rating has decreased in a specific country, language, or on specific device, additional details may be mentioned in the alert.
4. Uninstalls.

Reference: https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/3433208

Comment: You are right, however those particular alerts have never been triggered for me, although some of the app had actually suffered from multiple low ratings. I cannot see any other customization apart from whether I want to receive alerts or not - no way found yet to actually modify the alerts themselves, so I could receive for example only alerts on crashes and ratings and only if they reach threshold set by me.

Comment: Sorry to hear you're having issues! To report problems related to Google Play Developer Console, you can contact Google via email (English, Korean, Chinese, and Japanese): https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/#contact=1 (Send feedback & report bugs). They'll reply within 2 business days.